# How can i update user table when profile table update?

Tags: django

I have profile model,i want to update user model when is_active field in this model changed

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True,     null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

when is_active field in profile model update,i want update is_active field in user model in django.

```
Profile.objects.filter(pk=user_id).update(is_active=status)
```

Comment: Either implement your update of `is_active` as a method that performs the update in the user model too or check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/.

Comment: can you explain in code?

Comment: Exactly *why* do you add an `is_active` at the `Profile` as well, and not just take it from the `user` model? Data duplication is a (severe) anti-pattern.

Comment: @arezoo88: but you can simply use two forms in the same HTML page, one with fields for the user, and one with fields for the `Profile`. The person who fills it in does not "know" that these are two different models. It makes your database smaller, but furthermore, the odds of mistakes between the `User` and the `Profile` are less.